# Can I access downloaded files from an Android application

Tags: android

I want to build an application that is able to read `.CSV` files.
These .CSV files are downloaded NOT from within the application but just the regular Android browser.

Now, when I start my custom application, is that download available to me? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Everything downloaded from the browser is stored in `/sdcard/download`.

- Add the appropriate permission in the manifest:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Get the path to the SDCard by using [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) method.
- Use Java's `File()` or some library to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Files downloaded with the browser on my HTC Hero ends up in `/scard/download/`. Other browsers might place the files in the same location. The files in that directory are available to your app just as any other files in the file system. Handle them as you would any other file.

Answer (score 0):

[DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) has the ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE intent that your Activity can listen for. This will notify you everytime a download completes.